# JSF2 - Primefaces onbeforeunload and updating page content (uicomponent)

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, onbeforeunload

In a primefaces app, I need to warn users if they leave a form without submitting.

I use a template and the navigation is almost entirely done by changing the content of the main zone.

Template :

```
<h:panelGroup id="mainForm" layout="block">
    <ui:insert name="content" />
</h:panelGroup >
```

Template client :

`<ui:define name="content">
    <ui:include src="pages/#{appView.content}.xhtml" />
</ui:define>`

and the backing bean :

```
RequestContext context = RequestContext.getCurrentInstance();
appView.setContent("some_page");
context.update("mainForm");
```

I have seen the solutions using "onbeforeunload" but it only triggers if the user leaves the entire page, not when the content of a zone is updated.

Any pointers would be much appreciated

Comment: I would add a beforeunload to the page when the data is dirty...

Comment: Isn't the beforeunload only triggered when I leave the page ? I have a single page application, ie I never leave the page, only update content zones.

Comment: via ajax? Then override the global ajax handler to do a dirty check and ask for confirmation if required